# Is it possible to edit HTML files in Angular applications while running them in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017

**What I have**

I am completely new to Angular and I appreciate it wasn't designed to be run from Visual Studio 2017, however it certainly seems it can be done and there is even a VS project template for doing so.

Right now, my code is entirely the default that comes from this project template:

> VS 2017 > New Project > Web > ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET
>   Framework 4.6) > Angular

I can then build and run the project, and it eventually loads in the browser and works as expected. However, note that it takes a considerable about of time from "Start" (Debug > Start Debugging) to actually rendering the app for use - this isn't just a one off either.

---

**What I am trying to do**

Now, what I want to do is to edit any of the Angular HTML files **while the app is still running** and have my changes reflected in the app (even if that means refreshing the web page). For example, I want to add a new HTML element to the file:

> \ClientApp\app\components\app\app.components.html

---

**The problem**

The problem is, although I can view and edit the file fine, when I try to save the changes Visual Studio enters "break mode" as follows:

[image]

This then requires me to stop the application running, save the file, then start the application again (which takes considerable time, easily over 20 seconds or each change)... this is very time consuming overall (especially while still learning Angular) and I am finding it extremely unproductive and annoying.

---

**The question**

So basically, my question is, is there anything I can do to solve this problem? Is there a way I can enable editing the HTML file while running the app? Or is this something I just have to live with?

Comment: I just save the html (or the .ts), and then refresh the page and work for me :(. Use FireFox 58.0.1, Windows 10, Visual Studio Comunity 2017 ver  15.3.1

Comment: @Eliseo: Are you using the Angular template for Web API that comes with Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Angular template that comes with Visual Studio 2017 ([as detailed here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?tabs=visual-studio)) then you should have a folder in your project called "ClientApp".

Navigate to the "ClientApp" folder using a command prompt and run the command:

> ng serve

This will host the Angular application and will inform you of the URL you can use to access it via a browser, by default this will be: http://localhost:4200/

Now, anytime you make any file changes and save, the page will automatically refresh.

Comment: And where do I run `ng serve`?

Comment: You will have to open cmd and cd to your app's root folder (where package.json is located) and run `ng serve` in cmd. Note that after you run that script, a localhost url will pop up in the console. Just go to that url and that will be your website.

Comment: You can use VS as your editor and run your application with `ng serve` I just tested it in my Angular app. Normally we launch our application via IIS Express, but if you don't want to run an `ng build` after every change, you can use the serve script.

Comment: I get the error `"Unable to find "@angular/cli" in devDependencies."` and `"Cannot read property 'config' of null"`... I dont think using the VS project template I have used creates things exactly the same as you would normally expect

Comment: I suppose you have a node_modules folder and everything in your app root, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164354/discussion-between-rockguitarist1-and-musefan).

Comment: I don't know what went wrong yesterday, but today I ended up create a new project from scratch (with the same VS template) and it looked a lot more like you was expecting (for example, I have the e2e folder in ClientApp). So now your original answer works! I hope you don't mind but I updated your answer to add extra information to help others (and myself) in the future. I don't know why the project was different today though, perhaps it was something to do with updating the Angular CLI that we did because it's a version 5 project this time... who knows, as long as it works!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out for you. Ya it seemed weird you were missing a lot of Angular stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I also have an Angular application inside of an ASP.NET solution (and am using VS2017).

Run `ng build --watch` using the Angular CLI. Anytime you save your html, css, ts/js it will recompile your Angular application. A simple page refresh will reflect any changes.

If you don't have the Angular CLI set up then you need to install it globally `npm i -g @angular/cli`. From your Angular application root you can run your ng build command.

Comment: Thanks, how do I do that? (Yes, I am *this* new to Angular)

Comment: @musefan I started a chat with you. I would be more than glad to help you setup your Angular app for which you are trying to do.

Comment: @RoughChop: I get an error: `You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command.`... having been in a long chat with Rockguitarist1, its seems none of the normal suggestions (such as your command) will work because the project structure is so different when you use the template from VS. It is a lot different than if you create a Angular project manually with `ng new` command